# "The doors is closing" — correct?

Tags: grammaticality, grammatical-number, verb-agreement

A friend of mine tried to convince me that the expression "the doors is closing" is correct. It sounds completely wrong to me, but googling for it turns up some results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In most contexts it would be ungrammatical in Standard English. However, it might properly occur if ‘The Doors’ was the name of a play that was coming to the end of its run.

Comment: Ok, I already thought so. Maybe she picked it up in the "The Doors" context.

Comment: Since rock bands can open concerts, at one time "The Doors is opening" was a grammatical and meaningful sentence (in AmE, at least).

Comment: The Doors is opening would not work in English English, if the noun is plural the verb should be correspondingly conjugated - it's strangely literal when it comes to band names. Jim Morrison is opening would work. However, there are a number of cafes in Amsterdam called The Doors (after the band), where the singular would apply.

Comment: The Alfred Hitchcock movie "The Birds" had a pre-release ad campaign that featured the line "The Birds is coming."

Comment: @Lucas: true, but the converse isn't: if the name of the collective is singular in form, it may (but doesn't have to) take a plural verb in BrE.

Answer (score 2):

This is basic grammar.

Door (singular) + is.

Doors (plural) + are.

The only time you could consider using *doors* with a singular verb would be if you were referring to the band *The Doors*:

> The Doors was a band in the 1960s.

(Although some would say "The Doors *were* a band....")

Comment: Oh yes, sites like Wikipedia would say it.

Comment: I don't quite know what @MrLister means by that comment (arguably, there are no other sites like Wikipedia) but it sounds as if it was intended to be pointed. As Lucas points out in a comment above, most BrE speakers would say it.

Comment: Companies of people are often referred to in plural in BrE. The Who *are*, Manchester United *are*, IBM *are*, etc.

Comment: @ColinFine Sorry, I just meant that Wikipedia _does_ say "The Doors were a band..." (to show a real life example.) Wasn't trying to confuse anyone.